# transaction abort/rollback with unknown exception

Tags: transactions

I have 2 questions

1) does the first exception cause the transaction aborted? then causing the TransactionRollBackException?

2) what's the 1st exception means?

error logs:
https://community.jboss.org/message/859152#859152

Comment: Please trim that stacktrace to the relevant part and format your question properly.

Comment: I can't format the log properly, so put a link show the proper format, Thanks!